# Auth0 JWT. AuthHttp not sending Bearer in header

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, auth0

As far as I know WebApi AuthorizeAttribute will search for Bearer header to get access token from there. But seemes like AuthHttp not sending this header.

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Host:localhost:58928
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:4200/catalogues
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.3
```

This is how it configured

```
export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    tokenName: 'token',
    noJwtError: true,
    tokenGetter: (() => sessionStorage.getItem('token')),
    globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}],
  }), http, options);
}
....

    providers: [
        SearchService,
        DataService,
        StorageService,
        LocalStorageService,
        AuthService,
        {
          provide: AuthHttp,
          useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
          deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
        },
        AuthGuard
      ],
```

And then WebApi Controller

```
[ScopeAuthorize("read:userprofile")]

    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(CatalogueListDto))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
        var result = await _catalogueService.GetCatalogues();
        if (result == null) return BadRequest(ActionAnswer.Failed.CatalogueNotFound);
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to call the token endpoint of the web api to generate the bearer token first. That usually is api/token. Then you need to add that token to your request headers in angular under the name Authorization followed by 'bearer ' + token

Comment: try to set no-errors flag to false: `noJwtError: false`. Your issue may be caused by expired token error for example, post your error if any after unsetting no-errors flag,